# NativeScript Vue CSS Background Image repeat

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I am trying to make a very simple side-scrolling/parallax page that has 3 layered "divs" with animated backgrounds running on Android 25.

```
    <AbsoluteLayout width = "100%" height = "100%" class = "city">
        <AbsoluteLayout width = "200%" height = "100%" backgroundRepeat = "repeatX" bottom = "0" class = "parallax2"></AbsoluteLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout width = "200%" height = "100%" backgroundRepeat = "repeatX" bottom = "0" class = "parallax3"></AbsoluteLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout width = "400%" height = "100%" backgroundRepeat = "repeatX" bottom = "0" left = "-100%" class = "parallax"></AbsoluteLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

The problem is that the CSS for repeat-x does not work!

```
background-image: url('~/images/parallax0.png');
background-position: bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

If I change repeat-x to just repeat, then the image will repeat vertically (y), and same if I remove `background-repeat` altogether, but I cannot get the image to repeat on the horizontally (x) as well.

What am I missing? Is this a nativescript bug?